# For any entourage $U,V$  there's an entourage $W$ such that $U\circ W\subseteq V\circ U$

Tags: uniform-spaces, gn.general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal U)$ be a uniform space and let $U\in \mathcal U$. Is this statement true?
$$\forall V\in \mathcal U, \exists W\in \mathcal U, U\circ W\subseteq V\circ U$$

I think if the above statement is true then we can easily prove:
$$\forall V\in \mathcal U, \exists W\in \mathcal U, W\circ U\subseteq U\circ V$$

Comment: 1) I am a bit confused between the text and the title of your "question".


Comment: What do you mean exactly by $VU$ and $UW$? The product of these entourages? Are you working in a topological group?

Comment: $UV$ is $UoV$. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Need some motivation. Why do you care about this result? Why is this "research-level?"

Comment: I just tried many cases to find a counterexample for this. But I could not. I think finding a counterexample is not simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement follows from the first one by passing to inverses (i.e. reflecting along the diagonal).

Now consider the uniform structure on $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contain an open neighborhood of the diagonal.

Just to avoid confusion with left and right, I want to use the notation
$U\circ V = \{(x,z)| \exists y: (x,y)\in U \wedge (y,z)\in V\}.$

Let $U:=\{(x,y)| |y-x|<1 \}\cup  \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$.
$V:=\{(x,y)| |y-x|<1 \}$. 
Then $V\circ U=\{(x,y)| |y-x|<2 \}\cup \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$.

Now let $W$ be any entourage and let $Z$ be some open neighborhood of $0$ such that $\{0\}\times Z\subset  W$. Then $U\circ W$ will contain $\mathbb{R}\times Z$. Thus $U\circ W$ will not be contained in $V\circ U$. Since $W$ was arbitrary this should be a counterexample.

Comment: My tries teached me: $U o W = (W^{-1}oU^{-1})^{-1}=(WoU)^{-1}$ and not $WoU$. too common mistake I made too!

Comment: And for second part $(100,0.5)\in VoU$ because $(100,0)\in U$ and $(0,0.5)\in V$ but $(100,0.5)\notin \{(x,y)| |y-x|<2 \}\cup (\mathbb{R}\times \{0\})$. So
$$V\circ U \ne \{(x,y)| |y-x|<2 \}\cup (\mathbb{R}\times \{0\})$$

Comment: @CC Thank you comments. I agree with your first comment. However your second comment suggests that your definition of $U\circ V$ is my definition of $V \circ U$. (To avoid this I included my definition of $U\circ V$). I still think this is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found an answer to a similar question. Suppose:
$$(\forall V\in \mathcal U)(\exists W\in \mathcal U)(U\circ W\subseteq V\circ U)$$
By axiom of choice,for each $V \in \mathcal U$, there's some symmetric $D_V\in \mathcal U$ such that
$$D_V\circ D_V\subseteq  V$$

and there's some symmetric $W_V\in \mathcal U$ such that:

$$U\circ W_V \subseteq D_V\circ U$$
and
$$W_V\subseteq D_V$$

so
$$W_V\circ U\circ W_V \subseteq W_V\circ D_V\circ U\subseteq D_V\circ D_V\circ U\subseteq V\circ U$$

Therefore

$$\overline U=\bigcap_{W\in \mathcal U}W\circ U \circ W\subseteq \bigcap_{V\in \mathcal U}W_V\circ U \circ W_V\subseteq \bigcap_{V\in \mathcal U}V\circ U\subseteq U\circ U$$

Now see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300376/is-overlined-subseteq-d-circ-d-in-a-uniform-space/350024).